# Creating a simple socket server to allow friend to download files from my directory

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I am not sure if this is the right method to go about it with Python but I have created a local webserver and opened up a port in an attempt to allow my friend to get access to certain directories on my PC. We both use Windows and was hoping to find a Pythonic solution to this problem.

```
import http.server

import socketserver
PORT = 7000
Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)
print("Sever at PORT :", PORT)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

My friend has access to the directory using my IP address, and can look at the contents, but she can't download the directories she is interested in. The directories just end up as html files when she attempts to download.
I can't figure out how to get her to download the raw contents of the directories she is interested in using Python.

Thank you.

Comment: Can she download individual files? Then make a zip pf the folder and share.

Comment: @venky__  Zip works. Only problem is if I have 50 gigs of data that I want to pass to her, I would like to break it up into small zip files, in case the connection fails (the connection seems to be slow 500kb per second, despite both having good internet speeds)

Comment: You can try making smaller zip files. After downloading all of them you can extract them https://www.webhostinghub.com/help/learn/website/managing-files/split-file  . Regading bandwidth the best choice is to use any cloud based service. But 50 gb is too much under any free plan. You can make like 4 google account(15 gb each) and share.

Comment: Directories *are* served as HTML files, by any HTML server.

Answer (score 2):

You might be better served with an SFTP server in this case. Check out https://pypi.org/project/sftpserver/

You can access SFTP servers from Windows using WinSCP: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_connect